# How to debug an AWS Lambda locally when you use a provided runtime?

Tags: c++, docker, aws-lambda, gdb, aws-sdk-cpp

I would like to debug an AWS Lambda function written in C++ locally. Ideally, I want to be able to step through my code (like you do with [GDB](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/index.htm) or any decent IDE). The way to do this with AWS Lambdas would usually include [AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html).

**Idea 1, debug using SAM:**

Unfortunately, SAM does not enable you do debug provided runtimes, since it "only" supports Node.js, Python and Go ([compare documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-debugging.html)).

**Question 1:**

Is there a way to somehow attach GDB to the my compiled lambda function?

**Idea 2, run using docker-lambda:**

You can also start your function using [lambci/docker-lambda](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda). If you would like to get some debugging output, you could do  `strace docker run --rm -v my/build/dir:/var/task lambci/lambda:provided handler '{"some": "event"}'`. This works, but is not really the quality of debugging that I am looking for.

**Question 2:**

Can I somehow attach a to a lambda function that is running in `docker-lambda`?

**Idea 3: remote**:

Be desperate and go for anything you can get (this is NOT what I wanna do).

**Question 3:**

If there is really no way to do this locally, how should I do it on AWS?